# Need help getting to nth level of an adjacency matrix (graph) using a breadth-first search (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search, directed-graph, adjacency-matrix

[image]
[image]

```
public int bfs(int maxDepth){
        int src = 2;
        int dest = 2;
        int i;
        int depth = 0;
        int countPaths = 0;
        int element;

        queue.add(src);

        while(!queue.isEmpty() && depth <= maxDepth)
        {   
            element = queue.remove();
            i = 0;

            while(i < 5) 
            {   
                if(arr[element][i] > 0)
                {
                    queue.add(i);

                    if(i == dest)
                        countPaths++;
                }       
                i++;
            }
        }

        queue.clear();
        return countPaths;
    }
```

Hello!! Given a source and a destination, I need to find a path. My BFS algorithm is working fine as far as traversing the graph goes. My problem is getting it to stop when I want it to. I took out where I was incrementing depth so I don't look like a complete idiot. I hope someone can help. Essentially I want to know how I can keep track of the current depth. Thank you!

Example:

Find the # of paths from C to C with a maximum number of 3 stops. The answer is two paths:

C -> D -> C (2 stops)

C -> E -> B -> C (3 stops)

Example 2: Find the # of paths from A to C with a maximum number of 3 stops. The answer is three paths.

A -> B -> C (2 stops)

A -> D -> C (2 stops)

A -> E -> B -> C -> (3 stops)

Comment: Hi, it does not look like you could just use one variable `depth` to measure how deep you are going. Have you considered using another queue to keep track of depth? let's call it `depth_queue`. Each element in `depth_queue` is the depth of an element in `queue`. The way I see it, there are two strategies to detect when to terminate:
(1) the head of `depth_queue` is more than `maxDepth` (not sure if this is the case, you need to think on it)
(2) this is more assuring: go through the entire `depth_queue` if every element is more than `maxDepth`, then you can terminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Q:** Essentially I want to know how I can keep track of the current depth.

One solution is to create a wrapper class with an additional field, *depth*, as @svs explained in his answer. But, there is a neat trick which avoids creating a wrapper class and it is quite simpler:

```
queue.add(src);
while(!queue.isEmpty())
{
     int size = queue.size();
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
     {
     .. //do processing for the current depth
     }
}
```

In the `for` loop do whatever you intend to do with nodes of that level, including putting new elements in a queue (that would be nodes with depth equal current_depth + 1). Iterating only `queue.size()` times in `for` loop will guarantee that you process only the nodes of the current level, and `while` loop will guarantee that all levels will be processed (or just some of them, if you extend the condition for stopping the loop).

Answer (score 0):

Since every node should be associated with its depth when you perform the bfs you could create a class in which you store the node and the depth (and the parent if you want to print the path):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BFSTest {
    public static class BFSNode {
        public int node, depth;
        public BFSNode parent;

        public BFSNode(int node) {
            this.node = node;
            this.depth = 0;
            this.parent = null;
        }

        public BFSNode(int node, BFSNode parent) {
            this.node = node;
            this.depth = parent.depth+1;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    }

    ArrayDeque<BFSNode> queue;
    int[][] arr;

    public BFSTest() {
        queue = new ArrayDeque<BFSNode>();
        arr = new int[5][5];
        arr[0][1] = arr[0][3] = arr[0][4] = 1;
        arr[1][2] = 1;
        arr[2][3] = arr[2][4] = 1;
        arr[3][2] = arr[3][4] = 1;
        arr[4][1] = 1;
    }

    public int bfs(int src, int dest, int maxDepth){
        int i;
        int countPaths = 0;
        BFSNode element;

        queue.add(new BFSNode(src));

        while(!queue.isEmpty())
        {   
            element = queue.poll();
            if (element.depth > maxDepth)
                break;
            i = 0;

            while(i < 5) 
            {   
                if(arr[element.node][i] > 0)
                {
                    if(i == dest && element.depth +1 <= maxDepth) {
                        BFSNode tmp = element;
                        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        path.add(dest);
                        while (tmp != null) {
                            path.add(tmp.node);
                            tmp = tmp.parent;
                        }
                        for (int j = path.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                            System.out.print(path.get(j) + " ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                        countPaths++;
                    }

                    queue.add(new BFSNode(i, element));

                }       
                i++;
            }
        }

        queue.clear();
        return countPaths;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BFSTest test = new BFSTest();
        System.out.println(test.bfs(2, 2, 3));
        System.out.println(test.bfs(0, 2, 3));
    }

}
```

You get

```
//src = 2, dest=2
2 3 2   //path 1
2 4 1 2 //path 2
2       //total
//src=0. dest=2
0 1 2   //path 1
0 3 2   //path 2
0 4 1 2 //path 3
3       //total
```